# how to check whether a certain number is in the Pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

for a Pytorch tensor `A`:

```
A = tensor([1,0,0],
           [0,0,0])
```

is there way I can check whether the number 1 is an element of the tensor `A`?
like is there a pytorch function that returns True is 1 is an element of `A`, and returns False if 1 is not an element of `A`?

Thank you,

Answer (score 10):

`torch.Tensor` implements `__contains__`. So, you can just use:

```
1 in A
```

This returns `True` if the element `1` is in `A`, and `False` otherwise.